# My first HostGator based website is not connecting html and css

Tags: html, css, hosting

I'm trying to connect my HTML homepage to my CSS stylesheet. It works on my computer but it does not seem to work in the Hostgator server. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I tried looking around for answers and I came up with one solution which was to create a subfolder for the CSS under the public_html folder. I tried doing it but it didn't seem to work. When I refresh the page it's still the normal (unstylized) text of the HTML file. Here's my website: humanref.com . I've also tried routing the HTML to the proper location, which I think I'm doing successfully, it's just still not working.

Here is how the file organization looks on my host gator server:

```
-public_html
  -cgi_bin
  -css
    -style.css***
  -HumanRef
  -Default.html***
```

I want to connect the stared ones.

---(Note: I havent re-routed the UL yet because i want to make sure the css is working.)----

Listed below is the file called Default.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<nav>
<div class="topnav">
<ul>
    <li><a href="C:/Users/trevo/Desktop/Documents/GitHub/HumanRef/HumanRefrence/Pages/Home/Home2.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="C:/Users/trevo/Desktop/Documents/GitHub/HumanRef/HumanRefrence/Pages/Explore/ExploreMain.html">Exlpore</a></li>
    <li><a href="C:/Users/trevo/Desktop/Documents/GitHub/HumanRef/HumanRefrence/Pages/How to Help/DonateYourFace.html">How To Help</a></li>
    <li><a href="C:/Users/trevo/Desktop/Documents/GitHub/HumanRef/HumanRefrence/Pages/About Us/about.html">About Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
</body>
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /></html>
<title>Welcome to HumanRefrence</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="title">
<h1>Welcome to HumanRefrence</h1>

<p>Refrence the Diverstiy of Humanity</p>

<p><button class="button">Start Exploring</button></p>
</div>

<div class="Purpose">
<h2>This Sites Purpose</h2>
```

Like I said before it shows up as plain HTML without any stylization. What I expect is for the HTML and CSS to connect properly like how I have it on my computer. I don't know what I've done wrong.

Comment: As a general note, it is standard convention to name your homepage `index.html` and in your `<li>`, I recommend using relative paths instead of absolute paths. Also, you have a `</html>` after declaring your CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

really basic answer, but instead of figuring out the file system, have you considered placing your CSS inside a style tag in your HTML file?

```
<style>
   .box {
      color: green;
      border: 2px solid black;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Basic HTML structure**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="pages/site1.html"></a></li>
        <li><a href="pages/site2.html"></a></li>
        <li><a href="pages/site3.html"></a></li>
        <li><a href="pages/subpage/subpage1.html"></a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

More info: [Introduction to HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp)

Folder structure should something like:

```
public_html
    index.html
    css
        style.css
    pages
        page1.html
        page2.html
        page3.html
        subpages
            subpage1.html
```

I recommend using **relative paths** instead of absolute paths.

Answer (score 1):

Starting a link  with `/` creates an absolute path, which starts at the root folder, in this case `public_html`.

I find that sometimes I when writing a relative path it helps to say what each symbol is doing. For example:

`./` is the current directory I am in.
`css/` is my folder.
`style.css` is the file in my folder.

The OP was trying to link to the stylesheet with `/css/style.css`. The `/` means go to the root folder i.e `public_html`. Since there is no `css` folder directly after `public_html`, the link is looking for a folder that, as far as it knows, doesn't exist.

If wanted to start your path with `/` then the `href` would look like `/public_html_cgi_bin/css/style.css`.

Or you could just use a relative path and your `href` would be `./css/style.css` or even simpler, `css/style.css`